# Swiftui how to refresh parent view when child view closes on disappear

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a parent view called PostView which has a PlaceData state variable which will only contain an empty string . When you click on  the image postplace it will go to child view PlacePickerView . That view will have dynamic data from database . When you tap the Text **model.PlaceName** in that child view, that child view will close and we will be back in parent view . What I am trying to do is pass the value of model.PlaceName in the Child view (PlacePickerView) to PlaceData in the parent view (PostView) . The thing is that in the child view I am using   *@Environment(.presentationMode) var presentationMode* (since parent view may contain more data and I do not want to lose it by creating a new instance) to close that view and can not seem to pass data back to parent view . Any help or suggestions would be great .

```
struct PostView: View {
   @State var PlaceState = false
   @State var PlaceData = ""

    var body: some View {
    VStack {

            Text(PlaceData)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .font(.system(size: 17))
            .fontWeight(.medium)
            .padding(.bottom, 20.0)
          
              Image("postplace")
              .resizable()
              .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
              .padding(.top, 5.0)
              .onTapGesture {
               self.PlaceState.toggle()
               }.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $PlaceState, content: {
                 PlacePickerView()
                               
                            })
                }
            }
}
```

The child View

```
struct PlacePickerView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @State var model: MainModel?
    @State var tappedText1 = false

  var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(model.PlaceName) // I would like to pass value of model.PlaceName to PostView PlaceData on  when model on tapped is clicked here
                .font(.system(size: 11))
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                .frame(width: 106, height: 40)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4).stroke())
                .background(Color(UIColor(hexString: "#800000")))
                .onTapGesture {
                    tappedText1.toggle()
                        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }
         }  MainViewModel().MainViewRequest(newValue) { data in
            self.model = data!
        }
       }

}
```

Comment: Hard to figure out what's going on in your code. You're calling `PlacePickerView(placeEnum: placeEnum)` with a parameter named `placeEnum`, but `PlacePickerView` has no property named that. In a general sense, I think you want to look into what a `@Binding` does -- that is one way to provide two-way communication between and child and parent view.

Comment: I just removed that, my view does other stuff too but wanted to simplify it for this example . I will looking into bindings to see if it solves the issue .

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding) for Binding shows a very simple example of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
struct PostView: View {
   @State var PlaceState = false
   @State var PlaceData = ""
   @State var model: MainModel?
```

```
PlacePickerView(model: $model)
```

```
struct PlacePickerView: View {
  @Binding var model: MainModel?
```

This is the general concept you'd want to use with the bindings -- the parent owns it and it gets passed to the child view with `$` (to make it a binding). The child view uses it as `@Binding` instead of `@State`.

I'm assuming here that `MainModel` is a struct, by the way.

Your parent view will get re-rendered automatically when the state/binding value changes.